# Header hiding/effecting the divs comes after its

Tags: html, css

My header css is giving me pain. It's effecting what comes after it. I just want to put 3 links/button in center of the content. But when I try to make it. Not working properly. `p` tag or `h1` tags doesn't matter, Always stuck behind the header. I used clear fix but not quite working. I am not sure why next div stuck behind the header. And also when I try to give css to `a` tag which is inside row div. It doesn't take effect too.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

a {
  color: #000;
}

/* header */

.header {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.header li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header li a:hover,
.header .menu-btn:hover {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.header .logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* menu */

.header .menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}

/* menu icon */

.header .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 28px 20px;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 5px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -5px;
}

/* menu btn */

.header .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
  max-height: 240px;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}


html {
 font-family: Helvetica Neue;
}


.clearfix:after { 
   content: "."; 
   visibility: hidden; 
   display: block; 
   height: 0; 
   clear: both;
}

.row {
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
 width: 85%;
 color: black;
}

.button a:link {   
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: black;
 border: 1px solid red;
 padding: 15px;
}

a:visited {
   text-decoration: none !important;
}

/* 48em = 768px */

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .header li {
    float: left;
  }
  .header li a {
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
  .header .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .header .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
    <a href="" class="logo">GO</a>
    <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
    <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="row">
    <a href="#" class="button">Click</a>
</div>
```

Any idea why this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `padding-top` to your `body` and stick the `header` to `top` with `top: 0;`.

See below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  padding-top: 80px; /* added padding-top */
}

a {
  color: #000;
}



.header {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0; /* stick to top */
}

.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.header li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header li a:hover,
.header .menu-btn:hover {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.header .logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* menu */

.header .menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}

/* menu icon */

.header .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 28px 20px;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 5px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -5px;
}

/* menu btn */

.header .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
  max-height: 240px;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}


html {
 font-family: Helvetica Neue;
}


.clearfix:after { 
   content: "."; 
   visibility: hidden; 
   display: block; 
   height: 0; 
   clear: both;
}

.row {
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
 width: 85%;
 color: black;
}

.button:link {   
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: black;
 border: 1px solid red;
 padding: 15px;
  color: white; /* added for demonstration */
}

a:visited {
   text-decoration: none !important;
}

/* 48em = 768px */

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .header li {
    float: left;
  }
  .header li a {
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
  .header .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .header .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
      <a href="" class="logo">Reactive Design</a>
          <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
          <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
          <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
     </ul>
  </header>

  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="row">
   
   <a href="#" class="button">Click</a>

  </div>
```

Comment: thank you, but as  you see the a tag doesn't take css the that I gave it. still has the decorations.

Comment: and also still taking header css. floating. I want to put links as row.

Comment: It should be `.button:link` not `.button a:link` since `.button` is `a` itself, not a parent.

Comment: As for your second comment, if it's not yet solved, can you give more details about that? I'm not sure what you meant.

Comment: What do you mean under? Like giving more space between the header and the links? It would be better if you can put the desired layout instead.

Comment: okay, I solved that problem. Thank you for your help, really!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are trying to make the header always stay on top of the page (even when scrolled down) so you have added `position: fixed` in its CSS. This style makes all the other content start from the top of the page, rather than below the header. So you can either give some `margin-top: 80px` to the div below it or you can give `padding-top: 100px` to `body` and `top: 0` to `header`.

If you don't want the header to stay on top of the page while you scroll down. Then @Ana Liza Pandac answer seems a good approach.